# How to specify resource and id in REST URI using Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Here I want to specify the id in the path of a resource to get the respective object.

Example:

Consider we have 10 users. The resource URI path to get users is `/users`.

Now I want to fetch a single user by passing user id in URL like `/users/1234`.

How can I achieve this using Jersey?

Comment: you can pass attributes as a parameter in REST Call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`@PathParam`](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html).

```
@GET
@Path("/users/{id}")
public Response getUser(@PathParam int id) {
  // Fetch user and return Response.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use like :

```
@Path("/users/{userid}")
public Response getUsr(@PathParam("userid") String userId) {
```

Comment: Why `getMsg` if the resource is about users?

Comment: method name can be used  anything, rather that is a coding convention. OP just want relevant code how to get used id in rest not exact code